# ServiceNow Dynamic content Block Issues

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, servicenow

I have created this UI Macro (still under development) and included it into a UI Page and it works with no issue; however, when I try to include the UI Macro into a dynamic content block via a PA dashboard it does not render anything???

Full Code for the macro (give it a try):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">  

<script language="javascript" src="/scripts/prototype-adapter.jsx" /> 
<script language="javascript" src="/scripts/GlideV2ChartingIncludes.jsx" /> 
  <g:evaluate>
  var time = [];
    var newIncidents = [];
    var resIncidents = [];
  var incidentsJson = '[';
    var gr = GlideRecord('sys_trend');
    gr.addQuery('name', 'New Incidents');
    gr.query();
    while(gr.next()){

  newIncidents.push(gr.value.toString());
  incidentsJson += '{"y": '+parseInt(gr.value.toString(), 10)+', "name": "'+gr.collected+'"}',;
    }
  newIncidents = newIncidents.join(',');
  incidentsJson = incidentsJson.slice(0,-1);
        incidentsJson += ']';
  </g:evaluate>
<script>
  var incidentsJson = '${incidentsJson}';
  var incidents = "${newIncidents}";
  var I = incidents.split(',');
  for(var i=0; i != I.length; i++) {
  I[i] = parseInt(I[i], 10);
  }

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {  
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({  
  chart: {
  renderTo: 'newchart',
  type: 'line'
  },
            title: {
            text: 'Backlog Growth',
            x: -20 //center
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Growth'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '#'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Incidents',
            data: [{"y": 29, "name": "2016-09-04 21:57:21"},{"y": 28, "name": "2016-09-05 21:57:22"}]
  }, {
  name: 'Requested Items',
  data: [{"y": 50, "name": "2016-09-04 21:57:21"},{"y": 25, "name": "2016-09-05 21:57:22"}]
  }, {
  name: 'Demands',
  data: [{"y": 10, "name": "2016-09-04 21:57:21"},{"y": 5, "name": "2016-09-05 21:57:22"}]

        }]
    });
});
</script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="highwrapper" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; position:relative;">
    <div id="newchart" style="min-width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 20; position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;"></div>

</div>
  </div>
</j:jelly>
```

Code to include in UI Page or Content Block:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">
  <g:macro_invoke macro="custom_backlog_line_chart"/>
</j:jelly>
```

Works just fine when I "Try It" in a UI Page, but I get blank widget when I use it in a dynamic content block widget in a dashboard.

Also If someone can figure out why I cannot pass ${incidentsJson} to my series: data: in my chart that would be extremely helpful as well! Right now I am hardcoding what the json output is to display the chart. If I try to pass it to data: I get a blank chart...

I simply tried

```
series: [{
            name: 'Incidents',
            data: incidentsJson
  },
```

I tested in jsFiddle on Highcharts.com website and I can assign the json array to var and pass it to the series with no issue, but having trouble doing in SN.

Thanks in advance!

########UPDATE

Okay so I found two issues 1 was a misplace comma here.

```
incidentsJson += '{"y": '+parseInt(gr.value.toString(), 10)+', "name": "'+gr.collected+'"}',;
```

I accidentally put it outside of the ' ' so it should look like this.

```
incidentsJson += '{"y": '+parseInt(gr.value.toString(), 10)+', "name": "'+gr.collected+'"},';
```

The second issue was passing the evaluated variable to the script section should not have been in contained within ' '.

WRONG `var incidentsJson = '${incidentsJson}';`
RIGHT `var incidentsJson = ${incidentsJson};`

Next I was able to pass `incidentsJson` to the data series.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Incidents',
            data: incidentsJson
        },
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: I am able to render the chart however, still cannot pass a variable to the chart data series

Comment: Are you sure that you have correct data format?

Comment: Hi yes documentation states it can handle an object, string or integers. However it turns out that the i had a misplaced comma and quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found two issues 1 was a misplace comma here.

```
incidentsJson += '{"y": '+parseInt(gr.value.toString(), 10)+', "name": "'+gr.collected+'"}',;
```

I accidentally put it outside of the ' ' so it should look like this.

```
incidentsJson += '{"y": '+parseInt(gr.value.toString(), 10)+', "name": "'+gr.collected+'"},';
```

The second issue was passing the evaluated variable to the script section should not have been in contained within ' '.

WRONG `var incidentsJson = '${incidentsJson}';`
RIGHT `var incidentsJson = ${incidentsJson};`

Next I was able to pass `incidentsJson` to the data series.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Incidents',
            data: incidentsJson
        },
```

Output

[image]